# Microsoft Teams for Android "not compatible" on Samsung Galaxy S8?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, installation, microsoft-teams

I have Samsung Galaxy S8 on Android 8. I try and install MS Teams for my organization, but I get the message "Your device is not compatible".

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try downloading the APK from [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/microsoft-teams/#variants). The site is safe.